# How align to bottom a row div in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to align to bottm my row div or anyway tha last element.
I'm using bootstrap 3 and I have:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="logo col-centered">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 title text-center">THE TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-centered text-center description">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="description_arrow col-centered"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-centered">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img id="image-phone" src="img/image-phone.png" class="img-responsive" style="bottom:0px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the css I have:

```
#main {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Now It look so:

```
|------------------------|
|==========ROW===========|
|==========ROW===========|
|==========ROW===========|
|==========SPACE=========|
|==========SPACE=========|
|------------------------|
```

I want that look so:
Now It look so:

```
|------------------------|
|==========ROW===========|
|==========ROW===========|
|==========SPACE=========|
|==========SPACE=========|
|==========ROW===========|
|------------------------|
```

So I want keep the last row in the bottom, how I can do ?

EDIT: I can't use margin-bottom on the 2° div, because the distance between the 2° row div and the last row div, can change, and I don't want and high value, because then on 13" screen the page became scrollable.

EDIT2: I can't use position: fixed and bottom: 0, because under div #main, I have other div(always 100% height).

**WORKAROUND 1:**
I do so:

```
<div id="main" style="position: relative;">
```

And in the row div class I do:

```
<div class="row" style="position:absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;">
```

Seems works really fine, but I don't know if it's a good solution or not...please give me a feedback!

Comment: Do you want the element fixed (non scrollable of the end of the site)? Then you can position it via `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`

Comment: But after this div #main, I have other divs...so if I put position fixed and bottom: 0, It goes also over other divs.

Comment: That is right and in this case `position: fixed` is not the right solution. I couldn't get that fact from your question

Comment: Edited :) Sorry my fault.

Answer (score 6):

A solution is if you add to the `div` with the class container the classes `d-flex`, `flex-column` and `h-100`.

Then you need to add `mt-auto` to the last `row`. That will add a margin to all the space that is left on the screen. So this works on all screensizes.

Also important is that the `html`, the `body` and all elements above the `div` with the class `container` use the full height. You can achieve this with the following css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
html, body, #main {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div id="main">
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="logo col-centered">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 title text-center">THE TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-centered text-center description">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="description_arrow col-centered"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-auto mb-3">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-centered">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img id="image-phone" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png" class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 100px; bottom:0px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer creating a `spacer` class like this:

```
.spacer{
    height: height in %;
}
```

Then just add the `spacer` class like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="spacer">
<div class="row">
```

That way, you can easily have a space between rows that is responsive.

EDIT:

if you have a page that is not higher then 1280px you can try it makes the last row stick to the bottom of the page

```
.row:last-child {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful maybe, but doesn't directly answer OP's question, you're mentioning how to hard code a specific height for a spacer, but OP wants a "sticky" footer at the bottom of their page

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly - can't you just add `margin-bottom` to the second row to create the vertical space between the second and third row?

Also note that `col-12`'s can just be divs inside a container, they don't need a row or the col-12 class.

Comment: Ok for col-12.
Anyway I don't want use margin-bottom, because I don't know what is the distance between 2° row and last...the distance can change, and I don't want that the page became scrollable!

Comment: You might have to use javascript to figure out the size of the page & how much spacing room you have, and add `margin-bottom` accordingly

Comment: Yes this is a solution...I have wrote also a workaround(you can see in my question). You can give me a feedback ? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some margin between them by putting a div between that rows like `<div class="top-buffer">`and the css is here `.top-buffer { margin-top:10px; }` I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't want put a margin, because then the margin is different from screen to screen(example 13" vs 27").

Comment: well you can add further css to handle the screen resolution as well but its ok bootstrap is giving every thing just read in good way like <div class="sm-visible"></div> which handle the screen resolution

Comment: use some <div class="sm-hidden"></div> so you can just resolve the screen resolution from these classes too